# Getting a syntax error how do I remove quotes from json.dumps()

Tags: json, python-3.x, api

I'm getting information from an external api. I'm getting an error when I try to update the database as the string formatting is incorrect.

There is a mixture of Double quotes and single quotes caused by the single quote O' in the first line which must tell python to use Double quotes.

To get over this I tried json.dumps() and that gives me the result below and causes a syntax error when inserting to the Database, because of the single quotes around every object.

```
[
'{"author_name": "Michael P O\'Shaughnessy", "rating": 4, "text": "Stayed for a midweek"}', 
'{"author_name": "camille williams", "rating": 5, "text": "We looked around and found"}', 
'{"author_name": "natasha sevrugina", "rating": 5, "text": "Stayed at the "}', 
'{"author_name": "niamh kelly", "rating": 5, "text": "Great hotel in a central location"}', 
'{"author_name": "Janette Wade", "rating": 5, "text": "Excellent staff 
\\ud83d\\udc4f\\n\\nJanette\\nSpiritual Ceremonies"}'
```

]

It should look like this to achieve, valid Json

```
[
{"author_name": "Michael P O\' Shaughnessy", "rating": 4, "text": "Stayed for a midweek night"},
{"author_name": "camille williams", "rating": 5, "text": "We looked around and found"}
]
```

With out jsondumps the return from the api is, notice only the first line is changed

```
[
{'author_name': "Michael P O'Shaughnessy", 'rating': 4, 'text': "Stayed for a midweek night"}
{'author_name': 'camille williams', 'rating': 5, 'text': 'We looked around and found that was great."}, 
{'author_name': 'natasha sevrugina', 'rating': 5, 'text': 'Stayed at the Hotel '}, 
{'author_name': 'niamh kelly', 'rating': 5, 'text': 'Great hotel in a central location. '}, 
{'author_name': 'Janette Wade', 'rating': 5, 'text': 'Modern rooms. Great room service. '}
]
```

Which also gives a syntax error because of the mixture of single, double and single quotes.

Here are my calls to the api:

```
review_author = dictionary['result']['reviews'][i]['author_name']
review_rating = dictionary['result']['reviews'][i]['rating']
review_text = dictionary['result']['reviews'][i]['text']

dict_keys = ["author_name", "rating", "text"]
res_dict = {dict_keys[0]: review_author, dict_keys[1]: review_rating, dict_keys[2]: review_text}
bus_reviews.append(json.dumps(res_dict))
```

How can I remove the single quotes around json.dump()

Answer (score 0):

I changed this

```
bus_reviews.append(json.dumps(res_dict))
```

to

```
bus_reviews.append(res_dict)
```

and I put the return statement to include the json dumps

```
return json.dumps(bus_reviews)
```